# Function call and typecasting in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, type-conversion

Let's say I have a list

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

And I want to print this list by calling a function. Here is my function to print the list

```
def print_list(list_received):
        for var in list_received:       
                print var
```

And I am calling `print_list()` like below

```
print_list(x)
    |      |
 method   argument
  name
```

So above function call looks similar to one we used to do in C/C++.

Now lets say I have a list called `my_list`

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

And I want to convert `my_list` to tuple & I will be doing like below

```
my_tuple = tuple(my_list)
```

Now Here this `tuple(my_list)` is called **typecasting** as I read from here [http://www.pitt.edu/~naraehan/python2/data_types_conversion.html](http://www.pitt.edu/%7Enaraehan/python2/data_types_conversion.html)

now above **typecasting** looks completely different from `C` or `C++` as in `C` we used to do

```
int x = 10;
char ch = (char)x
```

My first doubt is what is the rational theory or consideration about changing `C` looks like  `(tuple)my_list` to `tuple(my_list)` ? Answer may be `Python` is not `C` but I want to know more.

My second question is how python interpreter will decides whether its a **function call** or **type conversion function** i.e both calling convention of `my_print(x)` and `tuple(my_list)` looks similar but actually both are doing different job.

Comment: but *type conversion functions* are also **functions**

Comment: Thanks @Ev.Kounis yes `tuple()` is also builtin.  But can I say here that  I am calling `tuple()` method in statement `tuple(my_list)` ?

Comment: There's no difference between a function call and a type conversion function. You call the `tuple` function. It returns a tuple. End of story.

Comment: But Normally in `C` explicit typecasting is not consider as function call, isn't it ?  In python `int(x)` and in C `(int)x` both works same but convention are different, where `x` is float variable .

Comment: In python `tuple()` is just a generic function implemented as a class or type constructor, of course there is an underlying C implementation for CPython

Comment: In python, `int(x)` calls `x.__int__()`, which could be `int.__int__`, `float.__int__`, `numpy.int64.__int_` etc. depending on the type of `x`

Comment: I'd say that there is no real typecasting in Python. In Java or C, `(int) ...` and such is a language feature, while in Python `int(...)` or `tuple(...)` is just a function that happens to accept e.g. a string or a list and returns an int or tuple.

Comment: Thanks lot. I got your point @Chris_Rands Can you tell the class name of that `__init__` method ? does it `tuple()` itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`my_tuple = tuple(my_list)` creates an instance of the class tuple from `my_list` object. It's not quite what a type casting like `(tuple)my_list` does in C since a new object is created.

`my_tuple = tuple(my_list)` is closer to the C++ `my_tuple = new Tuple(my_list)`.

Comment: Thanks. can you tell me path or source of tuple class implementation or python standard where I can see the implementation.

Comment: This is the [`tuple` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) and the source is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/tupleobject.c#L657)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Why it should be identified as a normal function or type conversion function? It is just a function.

Or as almost everything in python is an object, actually function is also a kind of object which implements `__call__`.

Further, there isn't a type conversion function in fact. `tuple` acts as an constructor, it takes an iterable object and return a tuple object.

Comment: yes I agree with on `tuple` being returning tuple object. But internally how it will initialize/convert list into tuple ? by calling some methods like constructor of the class ? correct me if I am wrong ?

Comment: Like Jacques Gaudin says, it does work like a constructor. It can convert not only `list` but any object which is iterable.

Comment: it does not work "like" a constructor: tuple is a class

Comment: yes @bobrobbob `tuple` is a class but `__init__()` method of `tuple` class will initialize it.

Comment: sorry, i was just being pedantic to avoid misunderstanding. it is not _like_ a constructor, it _is_ a constructor

Answer (score 0):

I may answer your second question, Python interpreter works on the basis of scope (local,enclosing,global,default).

for example:

```
def tuple(l_list):
     print l_list

l_list = [1,2]
tuple(l_list)
```

In above case it doesn't do type conversion instead it executes above function. Why because once we started execution it searches for tuple object and does job. If it didn't find then it considers default keyword and converts. In nutshell It is purely on scope of objects